# How create a role that only can create users?

Tags: users

I want to create a role in Drupal. I want create role assign to specific user.
Specific user can create only user and not anything.

Comment: do you have some advance? If one of the answers help you remember check it as accepted, if you don't know how, you can read this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi @maheshsingh , I just quickly checked the various questions you asked. I (and Adrian?) realise you're fairly new here, and I (we) know that it can be hard for a new user to learn some of the basics rules of this site. You have quite a few questions with negative votes, are you interested in some suggestions (via extra comments) to improve those questions (and learn from mistakes)? Also, is there really not 1 of both answers here you want to mark "accepted"? You'll gain +2 points for it! Also, don't forget to provide feedback on my answer to your other question. Just trying to help, OK?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: function contentalter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   //Check with your form_id 
   if ($form_id == 'model-node-form') {
    
             unset($form['author']);//remove authoring 
    unset($form['menu']);//remove menu options
    unset($form['options']);//remove publishing options
    unset($form['comment_settings']);//remove comment settings
    unset($form['path']);//remove url path settings (if path module is enabled)
    unset($form['log']);//log box
    unset($form['body_filter']['filter']);//remove input format
       
   }
}

Answer (score 3):

Go to `admin/people/permissions/roles` and create your role. Then go to `admin/people/permissions` and uncheck all the permission for the new user and check the Administer users permission in the User section:

[image]

To uncheck all the permission I can sugest you the use of the [Permission Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/permission_select) module.

> Permission Select is a module that allows for quicker editing of role
>   permissions on /admin/user/permissions.

And as Pierre Vriens says in his [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197471/how-create-a-role-that-only-can-create-users/197481#comment238427_197481):

> "do not grant ANY permissions to authenticated users". Because any
>   user with permission to create users is also an authenticated user.

Comment: Shouldn't this be combined with "do not grant ANY permissions to authenticated users"? Because any user with permission to create users is also an authenticated user. Get my point?

Comment: @pierre.vriens Yes this is a good idea, I will do this from my laptop because I now in the phone.

Comment: Wanna help "teaching" a new user a bit (like I did with my comment below the question here)?

Answer (score 2):

You can create roles in drupal 7 on admin/people/permissions/roles. Then assign the permissions that you want to that role.

There is a permission called "Administer users" but be careful because it can have security implications. Make sure that it only does what the user is supposed to do: test it!

Otherwise you could create your own permission with [hook_permission](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) and decide exactly what permission you want to grant.